# What is the way to enable Git-LFS in AWS lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, git-lfs

I'm confused as to what is the way to enable Git-LFS in AWS Lambda.

Do I need to create an arm lambda and then somehow install curl, sudo, apt-get to enable this?

Or do I need to use a third-party node module?